# Submit Form Using AJAX and Show Result in a lightbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, lightbox

What I am trying to do is when someone clicks on an image, an AJAX call made to a php file and the returned data will be showed on a lightbox popup.

Here is the code I am using

```
    $(".infoimg").on("click",function() {
    var theid = $(this).attr('id');
    var infofile = "http://www.mydomain.ext/info.php";
        $('.spinners').show().css({"display":"inline-block", "margin":"0 0 0 5px"});
              $.post( infofile,
                    { "theid": theid },
                        function(data){
                            $('.spinners').hide();
                            $('.infobox').html(data);
                        }
             );
    });
```

Now, I want to show the content of that `.infobox` in a lightbox after the data is populated within it. Or, even better, show the returned data within a lightbox popup without feeding it into any div.

There will be several `.infoimg` image class within a page with different IDs. the var `theid` is actually the ID of the image.

Please help.

Comment: That url should be in quotes.

Comment: Which lightbox framework are you using?

Comment: @AustinMullins, http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ But, I am up for any framework.

Comment: I can't get lightbox to work at all in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), but I have a feeling it will work if you arrange your images like `<a href="http://www.mydomain.ext/info.php?theid=thisImageId"><img src="thisImageSrc" id=thisImageId/></a>`

Answer (score 0):

I can't get lightbox to work at all in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), but I have a feeling it will work if you arrange your images like

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.ext/info.php?theid=thisImageId">
   <img src="thisThumbnailImageSrc" id=thisImageId/>
</a>
```

I tried out my idea on my local machine and it seems to work. Lightbox waits until it finishes receiving image data. It doesn't care what the extension is, so as long as the data returned from your php is an image, you can use this solution. I haven't got it to load arbitrary data like HTML yet, but I'll keep working on it and update this answer if I figure it out.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a PHP server set up anywhere to fiddle with it. I could try working on it with a Ruby server. The JavaScript should be the same either way, but I won't get to it today.